# CW complex as a disjoint union of cells - is the union really disjoint though?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, cw-complexes

I've came across the following argument in Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology", as part of a proof of some version of the Künneth Formula.

In the following discussion, $h^*, k^*$ are both relative cohomology theories. $\mu$ is a natural transformation between those. We aim to show it's a natural isomorphism.

$X^n,X^{n-1}$ are the $n,{n-1}$ skeleta of a CW complex.

I'm quoting the argument that's bugging me - the full text can be found at [Hatcher's web page](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/ATpage.html) - see Proposition $3.17$.

> Let $\Phi : \coprod_\alpha (D_\alpha^n,\partial D_\alpha^n)\to (X^n,X^{n-1})$ be be a collection of characteristic maps for all the $n$ cells
> of $X$. By excision, $\Phi^*$ is an isomorphism for $h^*$ and $k^*$, so by naturality it suffices
> to show that $\mu$ is an isomorphism for $(X,A) = \coprod_\alpha (D_\alpha^n,\partial D_\alpha^n)$. The axiom for disjoint unions gives a further reduction to the case of the pair $(D^n, \partial D^n)$.

I don't think this union is disjoint - It's plausible that the boundary of the cells intersect. Isn't it? If this isn't a disjoint union, how can one fix the argument?

Comment: This union *is* disjoint by definition. The *images* by $\Phi$ of the boundaries intersect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @AnneBauval. If you don't regard  $\coprod_\alpha (D^n_\alpha ,\partial D^n_\alpha)$ a subcomplex, how do you use excision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are confused by the word "excision". Hatcher considers the two CW-pairs $\coprod_{\alpha \in I} (D_\alpha^n,\partial D_\alpha^n) = (\coprod_{\alpha \in I} D_\alpha^n,\coprod_{\alpha \in I} \partial D_\alpha^n)$ and $(X^n,X^{n-1}) $ and the map $\Phi : \coprod_{\alpha \in I} (D_\alpha^n,\partial D_\alpha^n)\to (X^n,X^{n-1})$ determined by the collection of all characteristic maps $\phi_\alpha : D^n \to X^n$, $\alpha \in I$, for the $n$-cells of $X$.

$\coprod_{\alpha \in I} (D_\alpha^n,\partial D_\alpha^n) = (D^n,\partial D^n) \times I$  is the union of the disjoint copies $(D_\alpha^n,\partial D_\alpha^n) = (D^n,\partial D^n) \times \{\alpha\}$ of $(D^n,\partial D^n)$. That is, it is the *disjoint union* of these spaces.

Going to quotients we obtain a commutiave diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\coprod_{\alpha \in I} (D_\alpha^n,\partial D_\alpha^n) @>{\Phi}>> (X^n,X^{n-1}) \\
@V{q}VV @VV{q}V \\
(\coprod_{\alpha \in I} D_\alpha^n / \coprod_{\alpha \in I} \partial D_\alpha^n) @>>{\hat \Phi}> (X^n/X^{n-1})
\end{CD}
The induced map $\hat \Phi :  (\coprod_{\alpha \in I} D_\alpha^n / \coprod_{\alpha \in I} \partial D_\alpha^n) \to (X^n/X^{n-1})$ is a homeomorphism.

What Hatcher means by *excision* here is covered by Proposition 2.22 which is a corollary of the usual excision axiom. Applying it gives us a commutative diagram

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
H_*(\coprod_{\alpha \in I} (D_\alpha^n,\partial D_\alpha^n)) @>{\Phi_*}>> H_*(X^n,X^{n-1}) \\
@V{q_*}VV @VV{q_*}V \\
\tilde H_*(\coprod_{\alpha \in I} D_\alpha^n / \coprod_{\alpha \in I} \partial D_\alpha^n) @>>{\hat \Phi_*}> \tilde H_*(X^n/X^{n-1})
\end{CD}
in which the vertical arrows are isomorphimsms. This proves that $\Phi_*$ is an isomorphism.